ISV Subscriber Org Login logs still obfuscated
Sometimes when I log in to subscriber orgs from the Licence Management App, I do not get the full unobfuscated logs. Is there anything I need to do further to enable them?
This is an example of the logs I am getting (with the namespace changed):


Make sure you actually create the User Trace Flags using the Subscriber access; editing one that was created without Subscriber access doesn't make it work.

@PhilW I've tried deleting all the trace flags and creating them new again and unfortunately the logs are still obfuscated

I assume you are looking at newly generated logs, using the subscriber access created user trace flag? Previously generated logs do not have package detail added to them.

I am. I am logging in via the Licence Management App, opening the Developer Console and then getting logs there

Does it show a notification across the top of the screen that you're logged in with subscriber access?

It says "Logged in as Name (Username)"

I assume the package is appropriately registered against your LMA?

Yes, I have managed to debug in other orgs. It just sometimes doesn't work.

Well, you have me stumped. It really is as if the User Trace Flags were not created by you under subscriber access. Very strange. Perhaps something to raise on the AppExchange & ISV Technical Enablement partner forum?

Thank you for all your suggestions @PhilW

I contacted Salesforce and they were able to enable detailed logs for me. They did not explain exactly why the logs did not appear in this instance.
